# Зачем нужна условная компиляция?

Tags: c++, компиляция

Она позволит включать различные части кода программы во время компиляции, отладки или непосредственно выполнения?

Comment: Во время компиляции. Это же работает на уровне препроцессора. То есть после компиляции, включив какую-то опцию вы уже не измените поведение - потребуется перекомпиляция

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Условная компиляция позволяет включать в программу различные части кода в зависимости от:

- Платформы (Windows, Android, Linux, x86,x64, etc.);
- Назначения сборки (debug, release);
- Версии самого ПО или его компонентов;
- Других факторов обусловленных спецификой разрабатываемого ПО или выполняемых задач.

В основном использую в первых двух случаях.